# using cl-opengl with shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, common-lisp, slime

I tried to convert code from [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Introduction) modern opengl tutorial into cl, but if I start my program, a new window without something in it is opened, and I have to restart the whole window-manager, so it is difficult to debug.

my code (using sdl2 instead of glut):

```
(defun to-gl-array (seq type
                    &aux
                      (length (length seq))
                      (array (gl:alloc-gl-array type length)))
  (dotimes (i length)
    (setf (gl:glaref array i) (aref seq i))))

(defvar *vs* (gl:create-shader :vertex-shader))
(defvar *vs-source*
  "#version 330

attribute vec2 c2d;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(c2d, 0.0, 1.0);
}
")

(defvar *fs* (gl:create-shader :fragment-shader))
(defvar *fs-source*
  "#version 330

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor[0] = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor[1] = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor[2] = 1.0;
}
")

(defvar *c2d*)

(defvar *program* (gl:create-program))

(defun init ()
  (gl:shader-source *vs* *vs-source*)
  (gl:compile-shader *vs*)
  (gl:shader-source *fs* *fs-source*)
  (gl:compile-shader *fs*)
  (gl:attach-shader *program* *vs*)
  (gl:attach-shader *program* *fs*)
  (gl:link-program *program*)
  (setq *c2d* (gl:get-attrib-location *program* "c2d")))

(defun run (&aux triangle)
  (gl:use-program *program*)
  (gl:enable-vertex-attrib-array *c2d*)
  (setq triangle (to-gl-array #(0.0 768.0
                                1280.0 768.0
                                640.0 0.0) :float))
  (gl:vertex-attrib-pointer *c2d* 2 :float nil 0 triangle)
  (gl:free-gl-array triangle)
  (gl:draw-arrays :triangles 0 3)
  (gl:disable-vertex-attrib-array *c2d*))

(defun free ()
  (gl:delete-program *program*))


(defun start ()
  (init)
  (sdl2:with-init (:everything)
    (sdl2:with-window (win :w 1280 :h 768 :flags '(:shown :opengl :resizable))
      (sdl2:with-gl-context (gl-context win)
        (gl:ortho 0 1280 768 0 -1 1)
        (gl:clear-color 0 0 0 1)
        (sdl2:with-event-loop (:method :poll)
          (:quit () t)
          (:windowevent (:data1 w :data2 h)
            (sdl2:set-window-size win w h))
          (:keydown (:keysym key)
            (and (sdl2:scancode= (sdl2:scancode-value key) :scancode-escape)
                 (sdl2:push-event :quit)))
          (:idle ()
            (gl:clear :color-buffer)
            (gl:color 0 0 1)
            (run)
            (gl:flush)
            (sdl2:gl-swap-window win))
          (finish-output)))))
  (free))
```

what is the best way to get (modern) opengl working with cl?
should I use another tutorial (maybe for common lisp? I didn't find one) or other libs (for example a lispy glsl or not sdl2)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to call gl-free-array. You are not using VBOs, so OpenGL needs the CPU-side memory to render the triangles. You should put the triangle array in a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so it's gonna be an answer (and yes, I know this question is semi-old).
Your main problem seems to originate from your `to-gl-array`, which actually discards the array after filling it - returning `NIL` into your `triangle`.

```
(defun to-gl-array (seq type
                &aux
                  (length (length seq))
                  (array (gl:alloc-gl-array type length)))
   (dotimes (i length)
   (setf (gl:glaref array i) (aref seq i)))
   array)
```

should fix that part of the problem.